# Unable to set default form values in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to set default values for my form fields in my Django application, but nothing I do seemed to work. I am using Django 2.2.3.

This is my code in `views.py`:

```
def my_view(request, template_name="path/to/template"):
  form = MyForm(request.POST, initial={
    'field_one': field_one_default,
    'field_two': field_two_default,
  })

  try:
    if request.method == 'POST':
      if form.is_valid():
        field_one = form.cleaned_data['field_one']
        field_two = form.cleaned_data['field_two']

        my_model.field_one = field_one
        my_model.field_two = field_two
        my_model.save()

        return redirect('redirected_page')

      return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})

    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})

  except Http404 as e:
    return Http404("An error occurred.")
```

This is my code in `forms.py`:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
  field_one_choices = [
    ('Choice One', 'Choice One'),
    ('Choice Two', 'Choice Two'),
    ('Choice Three', 'Choice Three'),
  ]

  field_one = forms.ChoiceField(choices=field_one_choices, required=True)
  field_two = forms.IntegerField(
    validators=[MaxValueValidator(100), MinValueValidator(1)],
    required=True
  )
```

And this is my code in the template:

```
{% load fontawesome_5 %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}

<div class="container spacing-top">
  <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Save">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{% url 'another_page_url' %}">Cancel</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

I have also tried setting the default values in the `forms.py`, but that did not work either:

```
field_one = forms.ChoiceField(choices=field_one_choices, required=True, initial=field_one_default)
field_two = forms.IntegerField(
  validators=[MaxValueValidator(100), MinValueValidator(1)],
  required=True,
  initial=field_two_default
)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally found my mistake. Reading the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#initial) tells me the following:

> This is why initial values are only displayed for unbound forms. For bound forms, the HTML output will use the bound data.

This [part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/) of the documentation explains the meaning of bound and unbound forms, giving `form = NameForm(request.POST)` as an example of a bound form.

Therefore, to solve the posted problem, I changed my `views.py` code as such:

```
def my_view(request, template_name="path/to/template"):
  form = MyForm(request.POST or None, initial={
    'field_one': field_one_default,
    'field_two': field_two_default,
  })

  ...
```